# problems to run script in any IDE but in replit doesn't exist any problem -- JAVA

Tags: java

I'm new in Java, and this trial of the script runs in replit.com, but another IDE doesn't run. Why? I can't see the problem. Can you help me, please? Thanks a lot

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k, n, cpeso;
        System.out.print("change: ");
        k = sc.nextInt();
        while (k > 100 || k<0){
          System.out.println("input the correct number :" );
          k = sc.nextInt();
          }
        System.out.print("dollars: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        while (n > 10000 || n<0){
          System.out.println("input the correct number :" );
          n = sc.nextInt();
          }
          if(n<=10000 && n>=0 && k<=100 && k>=0){
            cpeso = n * k;
            System.out.println(n+" dollars equivalent to "+cpeso+" pesos");
            }else {
            
            }
  }
}
```

The error in IDEs like Netbeans, paiza.io etc., is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: What errors do the other IDEs generate? Do you want us to guess?

Comment: Btw, why do you have that empty else block? That might be one thing the IDEs are complaining about due to integrated style checkers. Another thing that I'd personally change is those range checks that check the upper bound first. You'd normally think of `0 <= n <= 10000` which would translate to code like `n >= 0 && n <= 10000` instead of `n<=10000 && n>=0` (the latter makes it harder to understand quickly and thus to spot errors).

Comment: [**Java !== JavaScript**](https://www.thesoftwareguild.com/faq/difference-between-java-and-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the error persists